# Rails controller action methods corresponding to static web pages

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, url-routing

One of my rails controllers is horribly overcrowded with a bunch of methods that link to static web pages.

**Controller**

```
def adventure
end

def cooking
end

def dancing
end

def programming
end

def reading
end

def running
end

def sports
end

def writing
end
```

For each of the above actions I have seperate view files and routes defined for them.

**View Files**

```
adventure.html.erb
cooking.html.erb
dancing.html.erb
programming.html.erb
reading.html.erb
running.html.erb
sports.html.erb
writing.html.erb
```

**Routes**

```
match '/adventure', to: 'pages#adventure', via: 'get'
match '/cooking', to: 'pages#fighting', via: 'get'
match '/dancing', to: 'pages#first_person_shooter', via: 'get'

match '/programming', to: 'pages#programming', via: 'get'
match '/reading', to: 'pages#reading', via: 'get'
match '/running', to: 'pages#running', via: 'get'
match '/sports', to: 'pages#sports', via: 'get'
match '/writing', to: 'pages#writing', via: 'get'
```

It is quite embarrassing to have code that horrible. Is there any way I can optimize that?

Comment: Just to clarify… those controller methods have empty bodies?

Comment: What determines the existence of those routes? The fact that a similarly named method exists on the `Pages` controller? The fact that a similarly named `.erb` file exists?

Comment: In those scenarios you simply create a single action with a param key.

Comment: Yes, all of those methods have empty bodies, which is why I'd like to change that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to define empty actions in your Controller.

Your code should work even if you delete all the empty actions, leaving you only with the views and routes:

page_controller.rb:

```
class PageController < ApplicationController
end
```

views:

```
adventure.html.erb
cooking.html.erb
dancing.html.erb
programming.html.erb
reading.html.erb
running.html.erb
sports.html.erb
writing.html.erb
```

routes:

```
match '/adventure', to: 'pages#adventure', via: 'get'
match '/cooking', to: 'pages#cooking', via: 'get'
match '/dancing', to: 'pages#dancing', via: 'get'

match '/programming', to: 'pages#programming', via: 'get'
match '/reading', to: 'pages#reading', via: 'get'
match '/running', to: 'pages#running', via: 'get'
match '/sports', to: 'pages#sports', via: 'get'
match '/writing', to: 'pages#writing', via: 'get'
```

or, if you *really* want things super DRY:

```
%w(adventure cooking dancing programming reading running sports writing).each do |page|
  match "/#{page}", to: "pages##{page}", via: 'get'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

An possible solution is use just one action in the controller so yo can do the following:

**config/routes.rb**

```
get '/:static_page', to: 'pages#show', constraints: {static_page: /\A(adventure|cooking|dancing|programming)\z/ }
```

Be aware that this route should be the last route, also note the constraint to prevent errors trying to render pages that does not exists

Then in you controller just def `show` method

**app/controllers/pages.rb**

```
def show
  render params[:static_page]
end
```

Then when you need to add a new page just add the page name in the routes constraint and add the respective view

Comment: Be aware that this changes your routing helpers.